# How did 'ex-' + 'serere' compound to signify 'thrust out, put forth'?

Tags: etymology, semantics

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adjacent&searchmode=none) avers the etymology for 'exert' to be from:

> 1660s, "thrust forth, push out," from Latin *exertus/exsertus*, past participle of *exerere/exserere* `"thrust out, put forth,"` from ***ex-* "out"** (see [ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***serere* "attach, join"** (see [series](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=series&allowed_in_frame=0)). Meaning "put into use" is 1680s.
>
> [ [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66113?rskey=mN3GMj&result=2&isAdvanced=false): ] [...] The formation is probably due to antithesis with inserĕre ([to insert v.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/96769)) [...]

***ex-*** + ***serere*** literally signifies 'to attach or join out', which doesn't make sense. How did they compound to signify `"thrust out, put forth"`? How ought this compound be understood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what is exactly unclear here, so I am sorry if I am misinterpreting the question. The *sĕro*, *sertus* has the semantics of binding into a bunch: “wreath; join, entwine, interweave, bind together; compose; contrive;” [Whit.] (There is also an irrelevant lemma of *sēro*).

*in-serere*, with the regular semantics of *in-*, directs the action of the verb inward, giving it the force of *bundling in, adding to the bunch, wreath or bundle*: “to put, bring, or introduce into, to insert” [L&S]

*ex-serere*, with the  *ex-* expectedly directing the action outward, essentially means *un-bundle, separate or protrude from, be taken away from the bunch*: “to stretch out or forth, to thrust out, put forth, to take out; to protrud[e] from the dress, [to be] bare, uncovered” [L&S].